# null is not an object (evaluating webrtcmodule.sendergetcapabilities)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I have integrated the 'react-native-webrtc' package into my React Native application for video call functionality. While it works perfectly on the iOS simulator, I encountered an issue when testing it on my Android device. Whenever i open my application, I receive the following error:

"null is not an object (evaluating webrtcmodule.sendergetcapabilities)"

I have installed it using "npm install react-native-webrtc"

here is image [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNxue.jpg)

How can i fix this issue.

Comment: That's very weird. console.log(typeof null) would always result in object.

Comment: The error means that `WebRTCModule` is null.

Comment: @Pointy yeah but i dont know why, because i didnt find anything about it

Comment: Well why do you think that `WebRTCModule` *should* be defined?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.